# Angular check if key exists in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, object

```
const respObj = {
  "Summary Details": [
    {
      "Assessment Summary": {
        "Total # of Questions": 3,
        "# Answered": 0,
        "# Not Answered": 3,
        "Score": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "Question Summary": {
        "Required Artifacts": {
          "attributeType": "TAG"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}

<p class="lmn-py-0 lmn-ml-5 lmn-mr-3 lmn-mb-0 lmn-mt-3">
  <span *ngIf="respObj && respObj['Summary Details']"><b>{{message.questionSummary}}</b></span>
</p>
```

With the above `*ngIf` condition I also need to check if this key `Question Summary` exists and its not an empty object because there's a case where I do not get this key. How can i check for this keys existence and where its not empty adding to the above condition `respObj && respObj['Summary Details']`

Comment: Would be a lot easier if you just used an object instead of an array of single-key objects.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Sadly I don't have control over this object :(. This is what i get

Comment: Then you'll have to write a function in your component to check if your `Summary Details` array contains `some()` object that has a `Question Summary` key. However, even if you get that object from some external source that you have no control over, nothing prevents you from restructuring it before exposing it to your template.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const respObj = {
  "Summary Details": [
    {
      "Assessment Summary": {
        "Total # of Questions": 3,
        "# Answered": 0,
        "# Not Answered": 3,
        "Score": ""
      }
    },
    {
      "Question Summary": {
        "Required Artifacts": {
          "attributeType": "TAG"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

In TS file

```
public isSummaryDetailsExist: boolean = false;

this.isSummaryDetailsExist = respObj['Summary Details'].some(obj => 'Question Summary' in obj && Object.keys('Question Summary').length > 0)
```

HTML

```
<p class="lmn-py-0 lmn-ml-5 lmn-mr-3 lmn-mb-0 lmn-mt-3">
  <span *ngIf="respObj && respObj['Summary Details'] && isSummaryDetailsExist"><b>{{message.questionSummary}}</b></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Strange that this answer got accepted because it contains  significant errors: 1) The absence of `Summary Details` is accounted for in the template, but not in the variable assignment. The variable assignment might fail. 2) `Object.keys('Question Summary')` does not do what's required at all.